minikube running on google cloud shell is unable to pull image from artifact registry - denied: Unauthenticated request
I am running minikube on google cloud shell. When I deploy my app using a command kubectl apply -k k8/config/app/app-name, the deployment is unable to pull image from artifact registry. This is the error I receive:

Failed to pull image "europe-docker.pkg.dev/sample-dev-xxxxxx/github-cr/org-name/app:v0.0.46": Error response from daemon: Head "https://europe-docker.pkg.dev/v2/sample-dev-xxxxxx/github-cr/org-name/app/manifests/v0.0.46": denied: Unauthenticated request. Unauthenticated requests do not have permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" on resource "projects/sample-dev-xxxxxx/locations/europe/repositories/github-cr" (or it may not exist)

Please note the following:

The registry is a remote registry that pulls artifacts from GitHub Container registry. This remote registry is duly authenticated while configuration.
As mentioned above that the above registry is duly authenticated during configuration,

I am able to pull the image using docker (on google cloud console),
I am able to pull the image and it deploy on the Cloud Run,
I am able to pull the image, using the the same kubernetes configuration, and deploy on GKE (google kubernetes engine).


I also tried using the Automated Google Cloud Platform Authentication addon for minikube but it said It seems that you are running in GCE, which means authentication should work without the GCP Auth addon. If you would still like to authenticate using a credentials file, use the --force flag.

Could someone please help me figure out what am I missing as the minikube is unable to pull the image from the artifact registry?
I tried to run the minikube in google cloud shell and expected no errors as the same configuration deployed the app to GKE successfully.

Thanks to the team at minikube who helped me resolve the issue. The curious lots may follow the conversation here.
It's the gcp-auth addon that did the trick. Here are the steps to resolve the issue:

Use the command gcloud auth application-default login to generate the ADC.
Copy across the ADC content at the default location ~/.config/gcloud.
Enable the addon by running the command minikube addons enable gcp-auth --force.

